# Need to be able to run an ajax call with element loaded after document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got checkbox inputs on a page and am filtering the results using ajax.

One search option is `type` and the `vendors` option updates depending on the `type` selected. But this means that the change function used to update the actual results no longer works within the `document.ready()`. To rectify this, I also call the function within `.ajaxComplete()`.

But as an ajax call is being called within the `ajaxComplete()`, it is causing an infinite loop and crashing the site.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){

  var type = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $.ajax({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'assets/ajax/update-filters.php',
     data: {type : type},
     success: function(data)
     {
        $('#vendor-filter input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
        vendors = [];
        $('#vendor-filter').empty();
        $('#vendor-filter').html(data);
     }

 });

 $('#vendor-filter input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    filterResults(this);
 });

});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){

  $('#vendor-filter input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
        filterResults(this);
  });

});



function filterResults($this)
{
    var type = $('input[type=radio]:checked').attr("data-id");

    var vendor = $($this).attr('data-id');
    if($($this).prop('checked'))
    {
        var action = 'add';
        vendors.push(vendor);
    }
    else
    {
        var action = 'remove';
        var index = vendors.indexOf(vendor);
        if(index >= 0)
        {
            vendors.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'assets/ajax/filter-results.php',
        data: {'vendor' : vendor, 'action' : action, 'vendors' : vendors, 'filter_type' : type},
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#results').empty();
            if(action == 'add')
            {
                window.history.pushState("", "Title", window.location.href+"&v[]="+vendor);
            }
            else if(action == 'remove')
            {
                var newUrl = window.location.href.replace("&v[]="+vendor, "");
                window.history.replaceState("", "Title", newUrl);
            }

            $('#results').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

How do I get the .change function to still work after the input checkbox has been called via ajax previously and without causing  a loop with .ajaxComplete() ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: _“But this means that the change function used to update the actual results no longer works within the document.ready()”_ - because you are replacing the actual input elements with the result of your AJAX call, I assume? The solution for that is simple, it is called _event delegation_.

Comment: You need to delegate the event from the body to the child. Something like this:
$( "body" ).delegate( "dynamicallyLoadedElement", "eventName", function() {
  //Do something here
});

Comment: Since your element is not available when the page is initially loaded, the event isn't registered. But when you delegate it from the body, the event is initially registered with the body and is then delegated to the element when it is available on the page

Answer (score 0):

Please try by change function as follow :

```
$(document.body).on("change",'input[type=radio]',function(){
  var type = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $.ajax({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'assets/ajax/update-filters.php',
     data: {type : type},
     success: function(data)
     {
        $('#vendor-filter input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
        vendors = [];
        $('#vendor-filter').empty();
        $('#vendor-filter').html(data);
     }

 });
```